# Mysql изоляция пользовательских запросов

Tags: mysql, sql

Я хочу создавать временную таблицу и переменную "user_id" каждому пользователю, который выполняет запрос. Потому что если сделать 1 таблицу на всех, то когда 2 пользователя сделают одновременно запрос - логика нарушится. 
Как я могу сделать это. Отдельное подключение каждому пользователю, транзакции? 
P.S. Использовать таблицы с user_id в имени - плохой совет.

Пример:

```
cursor = connection.cursos()
def create connection(user_id):
    cursor.execute('SET @user_id = %s' ,(user_id,))
    cursor.execute('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE user_resulte AS (SELECT column FROM results WHERE column = @user_id)')
```

Answer (score 1):

когда 2 пользователя сделают одновременно запрос - логика нарушится. У Вас создаётся временная таблица на 2х одна. попробуйте user_resulte добавить userId, что бы выглядело
для userId = 1

```
create temporary table user_resulte1 ...,
```

для userId = 20

```
create temporary table user_resulte20
```

Comment: Годная мысль, спасибо.
P.s. подожду еще варинты ответов.